# SQL apply function for each column of certain type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to save myself from adding lots of repetitive code to a set of data pull SQL scripts. I'm using SQL Server.

```
select 
    some_int_col, 
    replace(a_varchar_col,'|',' ')
from
    test_table
```

That is simple enough. It will return the text in a_varchar_col with all | replaced by a single space.

But I got like 12 tables and 100 varchar fields. I don't want to go through and put a replace around each column because its error prone and I'm lazy ;)

Is there some way to tell the select to perform the replace on all columns of type varchar?

A more generic way to ask this question would be:

Is there a way to have SQL Server automatically run some arbitrary code on every column returned in a select statement? If so, can you filter which columns a certain function gets applied to?

Answer (score 1):

This is for show and tell ONLY and my advice is not to use it unless absolutely necessary:

```
  DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)
SET @tableName = 'interiors'
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE columnNamesCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE t.name=@tableName
AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'dbo'
AND c.system_type_id = 167

OPEN columnNamesCursor

fetch next from columnNamesCursor into @columnName
while @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = ''
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @tablename + ' SET ' + @columnName + ' = ' + 'replace(' +@columnName +',''|'','' '' '+ ')'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

 fetch next from columnNamesCursor into @columnName
END

CLOSE columnNamesCursor
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best solution but this might speed up your script creation.  You can just copy paste the column names into your scripts

```
    SELECT 
        Case
            When systypes.name = 'varchar' then
                'replace(' + sysColumns.name + ',' + '''' + 'Replace' + '''' + ', ' + '''' + 'WithThis'''  + '),'
            else    sysColumns.Name + ','
        End,
--       column_name = syscolumns.name,  datatype=systypes.name     
    FROM sysobjects 
        JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
        JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
       WHERE
        sysobjects.xtype='U'    and systypes.Name <> 'sysname'
        and sysobjects.name = 'YourTableName'
ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a parse function that I always pass my sql through.  If it sees that the db is oracle, it replaces the "+" with "|" for example.

But I wrap all my db calls into classes that handle this plumbing and other things such as error handling and logging. So I can write SQL, pass it into my "GetDataSet" method, for example, and never have to worry about Oracle not liking "+".

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Can you write classes for SQL Server scripts? Or is your GetDataSet a method something on a model class written in Java/Python/whatever?