# Select All column with a Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is this possible in any way that I apply function on all columns in a SELECT. For example,

```
SELECT LEN(t.*) FROM Table t;
```

The problem is that the table is dynamic with dynamic number of columns and I need to apply a function on evry column.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235460/sql-apply-function-for-each-column-of-certain-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need some dynamic sql;

```
declare @table varchar(256) = 'the_table'
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = ''

select 
    @sql += case @sql when '' then '' else ',' end + ' func(' +  quotename(column_name) + ') as ' + quotename(column_name)
from 
    information_schema.columns 
where 
    table_name = @table

set @sql = 'select' + @sql + ' from ' + @table 
exec(@sql)
```

which produces & executes

```
select func([fld1]) as [fld1], func([fld2]) as [fld2] ... from the_table
```

Comment: Thanks, I am also staring to doing this.